# Calculate off current cell value, and place result into that same sell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to calculate an answer based off the value of the cell and have the calculated value replace that current value upon macro execution.  Example:  If L8 has a text value of 123, I need to have a leading 8 and nth number of zeros to make it 8 characters long. So the result will look like 80000123.  Below is the code I have thus far.  Also, I only want to calculate and replace cells visible in visible rows, because a filter will be in place.  Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rng = Range("L4:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).row)

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    If IsNumeric(cl.Value) And Len(cl.Value) > 0 Then
    cl.Formula = "=Text((rng), ""80000000""))"      'this line errors out
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the value stitched into the formula.

```
cl.Formula = "=Text(" & cl.Value & ", ""80000000"")"
```

To use that formula's result as a true number add a double unary.

```
cl.Formula = "=--Text(" & cl.Value & ", ""80000000"")"
'alternate
cl.Formula = "=" & cl.Value & "+80000000"
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick!  Although I want to keep the value in Text form, thanks for the true number tips.